# Android: NullRefException on creating WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to create a webView to layer over my main view.

```
    Display display = parent.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(size.x * 0.7f), (int)(size.y * 0.7f), Gravity.CENTER);

    WebView webView = new WebView(parent);
    webView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But I am getting a NullReferenceException at the line

```
WebView webView = new WebView(parent);
```

The parent is my main activity.

Error log:

```
06-11 10:44:03.110: D/Unity(18449): WeC2jetaiOI
06-11 10:44:03.115: D/Unity(18449): Get size
06-11 10:44:03.115: D/Unity(18449): false
06-11 10:44:03.120: E/Unity(18449): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 10:44:03.120: E/Unity(18449):  
06-11 10:44:03.120: E/Unity(18449): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
```

The false is the check if parent is null, right before the line new `WebView`.

Comment: Where is parent initialized? Also please pose the error log.

Comment: parent is passed in the constructor of the class, so that is not null, all the code before the new WebView is executed, but it does not get to setLayoutParams. I will post the error log tomorrow.